# Rdflib query value of a related triple

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, rdflib, turtle-rdf

On below example ttl I'm trying to run a query that would give me the `relationshipLabel` for specific combination of `subject` and `object` stated as `canRelateTo`.

So for example: I want to query the value of relationshipLabel for the combination of

- destination-org:Type-Data_Product, and
- https://open-kos.org/ext/kos-powerbi/PowerBIReport

which should return "Data Product consists of"

I tried it using this query (where `subj`/`obj` are for example the values above):

```
    query = f"""
    SELECT ?relationshipLabel 
    WHERE {{
        <{subj}> :canRelateTo ?canRelateTo ;
            :relationshipLabel ?relationshipLabel .
    FILTER (?canRelateTo = <{obj}> )
    }}
    """
    if (subj.endswith("Type-Data_Product")):
        print(query)

    results = graph.query(query)
```

But this query would return all values of `relationshipLabel`, so: "Data Product consists of", "has data quality rule", "is governed by", "see also", "is a data product".

Als tried various combinations using the `Graph.value()` method but without success.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Example ttl:

```
destination-org:Type-Data_Product
        :canRelateTo        <https://open-kos.org/ext/kos-powerbi/PowerBIReport> ;
        :relationshipLabel  "Data Product consists of" .

destination-org:Type-Data_Product
        :canRelateTo        destination-org:Type-Data_Quality_rule ;
        :relationshipLabel  "has data quality rule" .

destination-org:Type-Data_Product
        :canRelateTo        destination-org:Type-Policy ;
        :relationshipLabel  "is governed by" .

destination-org:Type-Data_Product
        :canRelateTo        dwec:BusinessTerm ;
        :relationshipLabel  "see also" .


<https://open-kos.org/ext/kos-powerbi/PowerBIReport>
        :canRelateTo        destination-org:Type-Data_Product ;
        :relationshipLabel  "is a data product" .
```

Comment: it's not the problem of your query but of your data. I think you somehow misunderstand the RDF data model. This is nothing more than a set of RDF triples. Maybe for you the Turtle syntax was a bit misleading with it's fancy short form and the blockwise formatting. The point is,  you attached multiple `:canRelateTo` triples to the same subject. And multiple `:relationShipLabel` triples. And the ordering here doesn't matter. In the end, there is no relation between `:canRelateTo` triple and `:relationshipLabel` triples expect for sharing the same subject

Comment: your data is equivalent to writing `destination-org:Type-Data_Product
        :canRelateTo        destination-org:Type-Policy ; :canRelateTo        dwec:BusinessTerm ; :canRelateTo        destination-org:Type-Data_Quality_rule ;` and so on and so forth. You have multiple options: i) use default RDF reification ii) use RDF Star iii) use an n-ary relationship i.e. some intermediate RDF node

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting into RDF just now and was indeed misled by the formatting. The TTL comes out of a product and I do not have much control over the output. Will need to find some other solution to address it.